# TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy generando una funcion que no me permita ingresar mas de dos espacios en blanco juntos pero me indica el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function[Aprender más]
```

este es la función

```
document.getElementsByClassName('txtparametro').addEventListener("keydown", teclear);
var flag = false;
var teclaAnterior = "";

function teclear(event) {
  teclaAnterior = teclaAnterior + " " + event.keyCode;
  var arregloTA = teclaAnterior.split(" ");
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && arregloTA[arregloTA.length - 2] == 32) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

y acá el HTML

```
    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Subrogancia <span style="color: red; margin-left: 0.3em;">(*)</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Subrogancia" maxlength="100" class="form-control txtparametro" name="subrrogancia" id="subrrogancia" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="limpiarCaracteresEspecialesParams('subrrogancia');" onkeypress="limpiarCaracteresEspecialesParams('subrrogancia');">                                    
                                </div>

                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Ley Prespuesto General <span style="color: red; margin-left: 0.3em;">(*)</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ley Prespuesto General" maxlength="100" class="form-control txtparametro" name="ley_presupuesto" id="ley_presupuesto" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="limpiarCaracteresEspecialesley('ley_presupuesto');" onkeypress="limpiarCaracteresEspecialesley('ley_presupuesto');">                                  
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno básicamente tu problema esta en que getElementsByClassName devuelve un array con todos los elementos que tengan esa clase (por eso getElements)

La manera de resolverlo es recorrer cada uno de ellos y asignarle el evento.

```
    let elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('txtparametro')

    for(let el of elementos) {
      el.addEventListener("keydown", teclear)
    }


    function teclear(event) {
      alert("sii")
      teclaAnterior = teclaAnterior + " " + event.keyCode;
      var arregloTA = teclaAnterior.split(" ");
      if (event.keyCode == 32 && arregloTA[arregloTA.length - 2] == 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

}
```

Mira [aquí](https://jsbin.com/liwahewese/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: el "let el of elementos" a que corresponderia ?  no entendí esa parte

Comment: Puedes utilizar var, pero utilizo let porque solo la quiero para ese bucler. Te recomiendo que mires este [Enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp)